# Read the file and replace its filename with current date

Tags: batch-file

Question 1:

I wanna append a list of filenames with a sequence no. at the back to current date , e.g.

Originally:

```
ABCDEFG-ALL-18269423.TXT
ABCDEFG-ALL-18269521.TXT
QWERTTY-ALL-18269530.TXT
QWERTTY-ALL-18269600.TXT
```

Result:

```
ABCDEFGJul01.TXT
QWERTTYJul01.TXT
```

(Copy and rename only the file with latest sequence no. to another folder)

Is there any basic script that can achieve this?

Question 2

I have  a list of files in the same folder which all begins with lines like:

```
CRM-678A      xxxxxxxxxx  xxxx
Unit: 1234     xxxxxxxxxxx xxx
```

I would like to rename each file into (using the above as example):

```
CRM-678A-1234-01Jun10.txt
```

Would you please advise a way to make a batch script for the above?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This might get you some of the way

```
@echo off
  for %%a in (*ALL*.txt) do call :EachFile %%a
goto :eof

:EachFile
  @echo %1
  set FileName=%1
  set FileName=%FileName:~0,7%
  @echo %Filename%
goto :eof
```

you can use the %DATE% env variable along with stuff you would find from running "help set" on the command line to do the rest